# Python/Tkinter: create recallable frame inside class

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to create a user interface with Tkinter and another module called [pandastable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html). I am calling the UI through a class because it keeps all my sub-functions active while the UI is active.

Here is where I'm stuck. In the course of this code it is necessary to recreate a pandas dataframe based on user input and then refresh the UI to display the new dataframe on screen. Hence what I need to do is refresh it using the class, but I can't figure out how to make this work. Here's the whole code. The refresh happens under the function "refresh_df".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

#Create the frame class and call my functions from inside the class

class UserInterface(Table):
    # Launch the df in a pandastable frame

    def handleCellEntry(self, row, col):
        super().handleCellEntry(row, col)
        print('changed:', row, col, "(TODO: update database)")
        return

    def refresh_df(self, df):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        f = Frame(mainframe)
        f.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
        screen_width = f.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.8
        screen_height = f.winfo_screenheight() * 0.7
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)
        pt.show()
        return

    def change_df(self, input_val):
        #Responds to button
        ui_df['Test col'] = input_val
        self.refresh_df(df=ui_df)

    def change_df_combo(self, event):
        #Responds to combobox, supposed to filter by 'Sec_type'
        combo_selection = str(combo_box.get())
        ui_df = pos_df[pos_df['Sec_type'] == combo_selection]
        ui_df['Test col combo'] = combo_selection
        self.refresh_df(df=ui_df)

pos_data = {'Location' : ['Denver', 'Boulder', 'Phoenix', 'Reno', 'Portland',
    'Eugene', 'San Francisco'], 'Sec_type' : ['mbus', 'mbus', 'vmus', 'caus',
    'vmus', 'mbus', 'mbus'], 'Rando_num': [18, 5, 34, 11, 72, 42, 9]}
pos_df = pd.DataFrame(data = pos_data)

ui_df = pos_df

#Launch Tkinter basics
root = Tk()
root.title("S test...")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

f = Frame(mainframe)
f.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
screen_width = f.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.8
screen_height = f.winfo_screenheight() * 0.7

ui = UserInterface(f, dataframe=pos_df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)

#'Test' button, adds a column
col_val_input = 'It worked!'
test_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text = 'Test', command= lambda: ui.change_df(input_val=col_val_input))
test_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W))

#Combobox to filter df
combo_choices = ['mbus', 'vmus', 'caus']
choice = StringVar()
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=choice)
combo_box['values'] = combo_choices
combo_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(W))
combo_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', ui.change_df_combo)

ui.show()

root.mainloop()
```

The key is these two lines:

```
        self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)
        pt.show()
```

These recall the dataframe just fine, but they aren't doing it from inside the class, so I'm not getting all the functionality. It seemed to me that something like this should work:

```
self.table = Table(f, dataframe=df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)
self.show()
```

But it doesn't. Again, I'm using pandastable here but I think the actual key problem is that I'm not using the right nomenclature within the class to make this all work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't access any member of class with this style. Your code not provided any `INIT` procedure. More variable/members not allowed to external access!

Answer (score 0):

Alright pandastable nerds... I think this is the right way to handle this. (showing the class only). Key is to use the updateModel/TableModel functionality.

I'm using it by changing around my DataFrame and then updating the TableModel, but IIUC the TableModel is effectively its own df, so you can update that directly w/o impacting the original df if that is useful to you. Anyway, my problem with the original code was that I was effectively creating a new df once the ComboBox event was triggered, and therefore pandastable didn't know what to do with that. You can manipulate the DataFrame and just call a "redraw()" and that works fine, but if you reconstruct the df, it breaks down.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

#Create the frame class and call my functions from inside the class

class UserInterface(Table):
    # Launch the df in a pandastable frame

    def handleCellEntry(self, row, col):
        super().handleCellEntry(row, col)
        print('changed:', row, col, "(TODO: update database)")
        return    

    def change_df(self, input_val):
        #Responds to button
        ui_df['Test col'] = input_val
        self.updateModel(TableModel(ui_df))
        self.redraw()

    def change_df_combo(self, event):
        #Responds to combobox, filter by 'Sec_type'
        combo_selection = str(combo_box.get())
        ui_df = pos_df[pos_df['Sec_type'] == combo_selection]
        ui_df['Test col combo'] = combo_selection
        self.updateModel(TableModel(ui_df))
        self.redraw()

pos_data = {'Location' : ['Denver', 'Boulder', 'Phoenix', 'Reno', 'Portland',
    'Eugene', 'San Francisco'], 'Sec_type' : ['mbus', 'mbus', 'vmus', 'caus',
    'vmus', 'mbus', 'mbus'], 'Rando_num': [18, 5, 34, 11, 72, 42, 9]}
pos_df = pd.DataFrame(data = pos_data)

ui_df = pos_df

#Launch Tkinter basics
root = Tk()
root.title("S test...")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

f = Frame(mainframe)
f.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
screen_width = f.winfo_screenwidth() * 0.8
screen_height = f.winfo_screenheight() * 0.7

ui = UserInterface(f, dataframe=pos_df, height = screen_height, width = screen_width)

#'Test' button, adds a column
col_val_input = 'It worked!'
test_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text = 'Test', command= lambda: ui.change_df(input_val=col_val_input))
test_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W))

#Combobox to filter df
combo_choices = ['mbus', 'vmus', 'caus']
choice = StringVar()
combo_box = ttk.Combobox(mainframe, textvariable=choice)
combo_box['values'] = combo_choices
combo_box.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(W))
combo_box.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', ui.change_df_combo)

ui.show()

root.mainloop()
```